# Fail2ban unban action fails with Cloudflare

Tags: nginx, fail2ban, cloudflare

I'm trying to setup Cloudflare blocking with fail2ban using this [guide](https://guides.wp-bullet.com/integrate-fail2ban-cloudflare-api-v4-guide/) and while it bans the IP correctly, fail2ban cannot unban the IP from Cloudflare either after timeout or with manual shell command. It always returns 400 Bad Request error.

Am I doing something wrong?

Here is the relevant cURL command:

```
actionunban = curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$( \
          curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=<ip>&page=1&per_page=1&match=all" \
          -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
          -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json" | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'id'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | head -n 1)" \
          -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
          -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
          -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Update: I can run the above mentioned nested cURL commands separately and they return correct responses.

Comment: Without looking closely, I use the same script, and mine seems to unban - at least I assume it does, because I see bans regularly but CloudFlare has only a small number of IPs blocked any time I look.

Comment: There's nothing in the log except the 400 Bad Request error. I had doubt about the cURL command. Can you diff it against yours?

Comment: Which log are you meaning I'll do that in about 12 hours when I have access to that server. I did things as I wrote in [this article](https://www.photographerstechsupport.com/aws-amazon-web-services/protecting-amazon-linux-server-fail2ban-cloudflare-wordpress/), which is an attributed copy of that original article you used.

Comment: The fail2ban DEBUG log.

Comment: I have fail2ban debug log working now. Waiting for the unban command to come up in a day or two.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looks like Cloudflare has adjusted their API to return formatted JSON (previously the returned JSON was on a single line). You should be able to fix the problem by stripping the new line characters before piping to the awk command:

```
actionunban = curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$( \
      curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=<ip>&page=1&per_page=1&match=all" \
      -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
      -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json" | tr -d '\n' | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'id'\042/){print $(i+1)}}}' | tr -d '"' | head -n 1)" \
      -H "X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>" \
      -H "X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>" \
      -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

You also might want to swap to the new Cloudflare filters that ships with Fail2ban 0.10, as it is much more succinct:

```
actionban = curl -s -o /dev/null -X POST -H 'X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>' -H 'X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>' \
        -H 'Content-Type: application/json' -d '{ "mode": "block", "configuration": { "target": "ip", "value": "<ip>" } }' \
        https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules

actionunban = curl -s -o /dev/null -X DELETE -H 'X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>' -H 'X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>' \
          https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$(curl -s -X GET -H 'X-Auth-Email: <cfuser>' -H 'X-Auth-Key: <cftoken>' \
          'https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=<ip>&page=1&per_page=1' | tr -d '\n' | cut -d'"' -f6)
```

Answer (score 0):

I think has problems with API's Cloudflare. I have try split out command unban IP as following:

```
id_CF=`curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=xxx.xxx.xxx.xxx&page=1&per_page=1&match=all" \
            -H "X-Auth-Email: <My's Email>" \
            -H "X-Auth-Key: <My's Token Cloudflare>" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json" | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'id'\042/){print $(i+1);}}}' | tr -d '"' | head -n 1`


curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$id_CF \
            -H "X-Auth-Email: <My's Email>" \
            -H "X-Auth-Key: <My's Token Cloudflare>" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

Resuit is: When run command second position then returns 400 Bad Request error, but when I get value of the variable $id_CF, suppose is the following id string: 71eceb59a7b846c6bd2b2692ab438e86 and run command second, again. Then it success.

```
curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/71eceb59a7b846c6bd2b2692ab438e86" \
            -H "X-Auth-Email: <My's Email>" \
            -H "X-Auth-Key: <My's Token Cloudflare>" \
            -H "Content-Type: application/json"
```

{
  "result": null,
  "success": true,
  "errors": null,
  "messages": null
}

I really don't know where does problem exactly come from, but previously, when I used the old API, it was not.

Answer (score 0):

Tks Jake Jackson,
You are correct!

I was test by stripping string the first blank line of ID and successed. Currently, I add the sed command to the pipe in the following command:

`actionunban = curl -s -X DELETE "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules/$( \
              curl -s -X GET "https://api.cloudflare.com/client/v4/user/firewall/access_rules/rules?mode=block&configuration_target=ip&configuration_value=27.78.160.247&page=1&per_page=1&match=all" \
             -H "X-Auth-Email: <My's Email>" \
             -H "X-Auth-Key: <My's Token Cloudflare>" \
             -H "Content-Type: application/json" | awk -F"[,:}]" '{for(i=1;i<=NF;i++){if($i~/'id'\042/){print $(i+1);}}}' | tr -d '"' | sed -e 's/^[ \t]*//' | head -n 1)" \
             -H "X-Auth-Email: <My's Email>" \
             -H "X-Auth-Key: <My's Token Cloudflare>" \
             -H "Content-Type: application/json"`

I hope will help everybody!